# Unable to Identify the Element in Selenium

Tags: selenium

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;height:20px;" valign="middle">
<div id="IconImg_iconMenu_icon__dhtmlLib_274" class="imo" 
 style="width:16px;height:16px;background-
image:url('images/main/galleries/icon16x16gallery1b.png');background-
position:0px -208px;margin-top:2px;cursor:pointer"></div>
```

Can anyone help me to locate the above element in Selenium. Tried with different element identification methods nothing has helped.

Comment: Can you provide some HTML sample and any code you have tried so far?

Comment: Html code is attached in my question.. driver.findElement(By.xpath("div/*[(@id='IconImg_iconMenu_icon__dhtmlLib_274'( and (@class = 'imo')]")) is the method i have tried

Comment: just try driver.findElement(By.id("IconImg_iconMenu_icon__dhtmlLib_274")) if the id is constant. otherwise try the xpath //div[contains(@id,'IconImg_iconMenu_icon__dhtmlLib_')]

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

There are few possible answers.
You can find with `xpath` and `cssSelector`.

Xpath:
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'IconImg_iconMenu_icon'"));`

CssSelector:
`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id^='IconImg_iconMenu_icon']"));`

In `CssSelector` `^=` means starts-with.